# Issues with Uploading a file with request

Tags: .net, api, restsharp

My API method

```
[HttpPut($"Create")]
public async Task<ActionResult<MyResult>> CreateAttachment([FromBody]MyRequest request, [FromForm]IFormFile file)
```

and my RestSharp call

```
Client.Put<MyResult>(new RestRequest($"{Resource}/Create", Method.Put)   
      .AddJsonBody(request)
      .AddFile("file", fileData, request.FileName)
      .AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"))!;
```

My restsharp api keeps throwing an UnsupportedMediaType exception, and when i try to debug the call in a middleware logger in the API, my debugger and app die with a stack overflow exception...I've tried specifying the content type in the call but that also fails.

Trying to write a put call that accepts both a file and also a json object with info on the file.

Comment: `[FromBody]` and `[FromForm]` are mutually-exclusive. And `[FromForm]` is intended for requests using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (i.e. HTML pages using `<form method="post">`).

Comment: So, cannot be done? IE would have to send the request, then add an upload method to upload the file sep?

Comment: Is this request coming from a web-browser client (a `<form>`, or AJAX/`fetch`/`XMLHttpRequest`), or from a non-browser client (e.g. `HttpClient`)?

Comment: Will be using RestSharp which essentially wraps around HttpClient

Comment: ...so why are you using `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: You can still specify headers in restsharp, one of the suggestions was to specify the datatype as multipart/form-data, then on your api definition it should autobind to IFormFIle via the [FromForm] param attribute and the body should bind to the other json obj param due to the [FromBody] attr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you're specifying the Content-Type header before adding the file and JSON body to the request, and that your API method is expecting a multipart/form-data request. If you continue to have issues, you may want to try using a tool like Fiddler to inspect the request and see if there are any issues with the request data.